# access outside variable in a class php

Tags: php, class, global

Hi i am a newbie to php,

i have a global variable in `index.php` which has a value.

**index.php:**

```
global customisedir;
customisedir="2016";
```

I  want to use the value of this variable in a class.

For ex:

```
class RainTPL{

        static $tpl_dir = "tpl/";
        static $custom_dir = "custom/".$customisedir;

***REST OF THE CLASS**

}
```

But of course it is not working ! can somebody please help.

Thanks

Comment: use `public $customisedir="2016";` or use `$` before the variable initialisation

Answer (score 0):

All variables in PHP must bear the sign '$'.

Try this code to see if it works:

```
global $customisedir; $customisedir="2016";
```

I would recommend to include this variable, if possible within the controller class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a variables from out of class without globalizing it as follow:

```
class RainTPL{
    private $customisedir; private $custom_dir;
    public function __construct($customisedir){  
        $this->custom_dir = "custom/" . $this->customisedir;
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

so when you call the class it will be:

```
$RainTPL  = new RainTPL($customisedir);
```